# Why does the .NET Array.Resize() method use an ref argument?

Tags: c#

Other methods like Array.Sort() don't use `ref` and yet they change the array.

Also this code confuses me:

```
using System.Linq;
using System;

namespace jmennyprostor {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] mojepole = {4,4,5,2,4};
        pole.changearray(mojepole); // this does change mojepole
        pole.resizearray(mojepole); // this magically does not change mojepole
        pole.resizearrayworking(ref mojepole); // this DOES change mojepole
    }

    public class pole 
    {
        public static void changearray(int[] polerole)
        {
            polerole[2] = 44444;
        }

        public static void resizearray(int[] polerole)
        {
            Array.Resize(polerole);
        }

        public static void resizearrayworking(ref int[] polerole)
        {
            Array.Resize(polerole);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/passing-reference-type-parameters and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions

Comment: Distinguish modifying the array *content* from the array *object*.  Array.Resize() creates a new array object, so needs ref.

Answer (score 2):

Because the array may not actually be resized.  So you pass in a reference to an array of size N, and the method may allocate a new array of size `newSize` and change your reference to point to the new array.

It has a similar effect as

```
oldArray = Array.Resize(oldArray, newSize);
```

if the method returned a reference to the new array instead of using a ref argument.